# Using readr to declare/parse three different types of dates

Tags: r, readr

I have struggled for quite some time now to read in a dataset and parse the proper date format using `readr`. My data looks like this:

```
short_name    full_name    month    Euro
       Jan      January        1      10
       Feb     February        2      20
       Mar        March        3      30
       Apr        April        4      40
       May          May        5      50
       Jun         June        6      60
```

What I do want to do is to declare the first three columns (short_name, full_name, month) all a month so I can later use them to plot in ggplot.

Variant_1: Here I try to read in the data and declare it

```
read_csv2(file = "abc.csv", col_names = TRUE, col_types = cols(short_name = col_date(format = ("%b")),
                                                               full_name  = col_date("%B"),
                                                               month      = col_date(format = "%m"),
                                                               Euro       = col_integer()))
```

Variant_2: Here I try to read in the data as character and later parse the proper format

```
read_tsv("abc.txt", col_names = T, col_types = cols(short_name = col_character(),
                                                    full_name  = col_character(),
                                                    month      = col_character(),
                                                    Euro       = col_character()))
parse_datetime(abc$full_name, format = "%B", locale = ("en_US"))
```

None of them worked so far and I have received a lot of different errors. Is it even possible to use `"%B"` and `"%b"` and `"%m"` alone to declare a dataset?

Comment: A month is not a valid date format. The default options for date/time classes are the `Date` class, which requires year, month and day; the `POSIXct` which requires year, month, day, hour, minute, second. The `zoo` package offers a `yearmon` class, which only requires Year and Month. If all you have is a month, you're probably best off leaving it as a `factor`. Alternatively, you could pick a year and just pretend like every row is the 1st day of the month for that year, and use the standard `Date` class. What's your goal? Why are you trying to make this conversion?

Comment: If you are just wanting to plot the months in the correct order, use the built-in `month.abb` or `month.name` variables to order the levels of a factor. `abc$month = factor(abc.full_name, levels = month.name)`